# Express the conjugate of $g(x)=\inf_zf(x,z)$ in terms of $f^*(x,z)$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Let $f(x,z)$ be convex in $(x,z)$ and define $g(x)=\inf_zf(x,z)$. Express the conjugate $g^*$ in terms of $f^*$.

**Solution:**
The (convex) conjugate of $f(x,z)$ is:
$$f^*(y,s)=\sup_{(x,z)\in dom~f}\left(y^Tx+sz-f(x,z) \right)$$

Also, the conjugate of $g(x)$ is:
\begin{align}
g^*(y)&=\sup_{x\in dom~g} \left(y^Tx-g(x)\right)\\
&=\sup_{x\in dom~g} \left(y^Tx-\inf_zf(x,z)\right)
\end{align}
Can I proceed as follows?

let $z^*$ be a global minimizer for the convex function $f(x,z)$, then 
\begin{align}
g^*(y)&=\sup_{x\in dom~g} \left(y^Tx-f(x,z^*)\right)\\
&=\sup_{x\in dom~g} \left(y^Tx-f(x,z^*)\right)+sz^*-sz^*\\
&=f^*(y,z*)-sz^*
\end{align}

Comment: Witthout looking into the details of your construct, I can already say it couldn't possibly be correct: your $g^*(y)$ deponds on the "global minimizer" $z^*$ of $f(x, y)$ you chose, and therefore isn't a *well-defined* function.

Answer (score 1):

Following your argument, $g^*(y)= \sup_x (y^Tx-\inf_z f(x,z))$. We can use $\inf_z f(x,z)=-\sup_z (-f(x,z))$ and get:
$g^*(y)=\sup_x(y^Tx+\sup_z(-f(x,z)))=\sup_z\sup_x (y^Tx-f(x,z))=\sup_z\sup_x (y^Tx+0^Tz-f(x,z))=\sup_z f^*(y,0)=f^*(y,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your bivariate function has two "pictures" attached to it, in that if you define for every pair $(x, y)$ auxiliary functions $v_z := f(., z)$ and $u_x := f(x, .)$,
then it holds that $u_x(z) = u_z(x)$ for all pairs $(x, y)$.
Now, define the maginal: $g(x) := \inf_z u_x(z)$, for ever $x$. One computes readily

$$
\begin{split}
g^*(y) &:= \sup_x \langle x, y\rangle  - g(x) = \sup_x \langle x, y\rangle - \inf_z u_x(z)\\
&= \inf_z \sup_x \langle x, y\rangle - u_x(z) = \inf_z \sup_x \langle x, y\rangle - v_z(x) = \inf_z v_z^*(y).
\end{split}
$$

In plain english, we've shown that
$$(x \mapsto \inf_z f(x, z))^*(y) = \inf_z (x \mapsto f(x, z))^*(y),\; \forall y$$